# jscolor doesn't work when the form is at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, jscolor

I have a form which is below the bottom of the long list as shown below, but the jscolor is not working as expected when it is at the bottom of the page. When I change the form above the list, it works. Please help if there is anyway to make it work.

```
<div>
  <ul>
   <li>fgdfg</li>
   ....
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
...
<input class="color" name="color" >
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your JSColor.js should load before the `<input>`

or your have to call `jscolor.init()` yourself, it will automatically find elements with **color** class and make them become colorpicker